# Which event triggered at start of Fiori app?

Tags: events, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to create a FLP plugin which executes and does some checks before and a will be opened from the launchpad. If those checks fail the app shouldn't start up and instead it should display a dialog which informs the user that the application isn't available right now.

So the creation and configuration of the FLP plugin was successful. But now I'm stuck because I don't know which event I need to listen to. While searching through the internet I found these to approaches:

```js
return Component.extend("ch.srgssr.zcaflpmntchk.Component", {
  ...
  init: function () {
    ...
    sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().subscribe(
      "sap.ushell",
      "appOpened",
      (e1, e2, appMeta, e4) => console.log("onAppOpened", {e1, e2, appMeta, e4}),
      this
    );
```

```js
return Component.extend("ch.srgssr.zcaflpmntchk.Component", {
  ...
  init: function () {
    ...
    sap.ushell.Container.getService("AppLifeCycle").attachAppLoaded(() => console.log("attachAppLoaded"));
```

Unfortunately both events are fired after the app is loaded and no matter what I do (or throw) I can't stop loading the app once the event is fired.

So on which event do I need to listen to be able the stop loading the app? Is there a "beforeAppLoaded" or something? Can't find a proper list of available events. I'm looking through several code examples and taking possible solutions from there.